# Fully remove a default program association for file types in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, file-association, total-commander, resources

Not a single answer from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/49615/how-do-you-remove-a-default-program-association-for-file-types-in-windows-7) worked for me.

I want to delete the `.resource` association with Total Commander.

**Approach 1**

I open registry, go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\\.resource\OpenWithList` and remove there all I can.

[image]

It does not work, the default app is still there.

**Approach 2**

I create a dumb `.exe`. Right click a file `.resource` select open with and check to always use the app as a default one. When time comes for the file to be opened I am presented with a window that tells me that `.exe` can not be used for opening the file. And hence again I did not remove the Total Commander as default opener of `.resource`.

[image]

[image]

**Approach 3**

I right click Window button. Go to Apps and Features -> Default apps -> Choose default app by file type -> Scroll until find the `.resource` extension and see that there are not options except Total Commander. Again I was not able to remove the default open with app.

[image]

**4 Approach**

Win+R -> cmd.exe -> ASSOC .resource= -> check that file association is gone, but it is not gone.

[image]

That is really crazy. What can I do to solve the issue?

Comment: [Assoc - File extension and Type - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/assoc.html)

Comment: @DavidPostill, is **4 Approach** what you mean? Just added it.

Comment: Hmm. What happens if you correct the spelling mistake?

Comment: "ASSOC .reource= " should be re**s**ource.

Comment: Addendum: `ASSOC` command should be run from Admin "Command Prompt" (cmd.exe) window and not under PowerShell console.

Comment: [How to Remove a File Association Using the Registry Editor?](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/remove-file-association-windows/)

Comment: @Win32Guy, thank you. Just did what you propose and it did not change the file association.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make Notepad++ default program for \`.txt\` files?](https://superuser.com/questions/1324367/how-can-i-make-notepad-default-program-for-txt-files)

Comment: @YaroslavTrofimov Did you get a chance to look over the answer I provided below?

Answer (score 8):

Simply save the below **Reg File** to a `.reg` extension named text file and then run the elevated command of `ASSOC .resource=`.  Afterwards, double click the **Reg File** to remove that registry key and its content from the registry to fully disassociate the file extension from opening with any apps.

### Reg File

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.resource]
```

[image]

Now when you go to open the `.resource` file, it will no longer have any application association and prompt you to tell it what app to open with.

You can delete this key manually by navigating to it via regedit and then pressing <kbd>`Delete`</kbd> too.
[image]

---

### Additional Resources

- [How to add, modify, or delete registry subkeys and values by using a .reg file](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/310516/how-to-add-modify-or-delete-registry-subkeys-and-values-by-using-a-reg)
- [How to associate a default program during application setup](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7f8db777-9729-4bed-adbf-3bfec510ce79/how-to-associate-a-default-program-during-application-setup-eg-pdf-files?forum=win10itprogeneral)
- [what purpose does HKCU\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\explorer\fileexts serve?](https://superuser.com/questions/558845/what-purpose-does-hkcu-software-microsoft-windows-currentversion-explorer-fileex)
- `ASSOC /?`

  > ```
  > Displays or modifies file extension associations
  >
  > ASSOC [.ext[=[fileType]]]
  >
  >   .ext      Specifies the file extension to associate the file type with
  >   fileType  Specifies the file type to associate with the file extension
  >
  > Type ASSOC without parameters to display the current file associations.
  > If ASSOC is invoked with just a file extension, it displays the current
  > file association for that file extension.  Specify nothing for the file
  > type and the command will delete the association for the file extension.
  > ```

Comment: @YaroslavTrofimov - If you wanted to be extra thorough you could also run the admin elevated command prompt commands of: `taskkill /f /im explorer.exe && explorer` to kill explorer and start a new instance of it after you make the 2 changes as listed above.

Comment: This was only half the answer for me.  I needed to also delete the same sub key from **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT**.  See https://superuser.com/questions/49615/how-do-you-remove-a-default-program-association-for-file-types-in-windows-7