# How to disassociate a file extension from a program in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

When opening a .tex with notepad.exe, I accidentally did not uncheck the 'Always choose this app' box. Now .tex are associated with that "editor". How can I completely remove that association?

I am aware of:
[Fully remove a default program association for file types in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1369556/fully-remove-a-default-program-association-for-file-types-in-windows-10)

Unfortunately, none of the approaches there have worked in my case.

Comment: The answer by Markus Meyer is very well set out. If it does not work for you, try this Windows OS Hub Article and look down the article for changing File Type Association in the Registry. Take very great care if you decide to try this.   http://woshub.com/managing-default-file-associations-in-windows-10/

Comment: I don't see how deleting the file extension key within `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\\.resource\OpenWithList` couldn't possible resolve your problem.  Additionally, why don't you just select a different application, if you want to use a different application instead.

Answer (score 0):

Running `assoc .tex=` would work for me. It is necessary to run it from `cmd` which is run as Administrator. The call without `=` sign is just for verification.

My usecase:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>assoc .jar=

C:\WINDOWS\system32>assoc .jar
File association not found for extension .jar

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```